# Insert Tuple Into 2D Array

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, tuples

I'm trying to insert some tuples into a 2D array, but for some reason, the x value doesn't seem to increase.

```
x_axis = 20
y_axis = 4
arr = [[None]*y_axis]*x_axis
for x in range(x_axis):
    for y in range(y_axis):
        arr[x][y] = (x,9,y,6)

for x in range(x_axis):
    for y in range(y_axis):
        print arr[x][y]
```

I'm getting this:

```
(19, 9, 0, 6)
(19, 9, 1, 6)
(19, 9, 2, 6)
(19, 9, 3, 6)
(19, 9, 0, 6)
(19, 9, 1, 6)
(19, 9, 2, 6)
(19, 9, 3, 6)
(19, 9, 0, 6)
(19, 9, 1, 6)
(19, 9, 2, 6)
(19, 9, 3, 6)
(19, 9, 0, 6)
(19, 9, 1, 6)
(19, 9, 2, 6)
(19, 9, 3, 6)
(19, 9, 0, 6)
(19, 9, 1, 6)
(19, 9, 2, 6)
(19, 9, 3, 6)
```

I have no idea why the `x` is sticking to 19 (the last number of the range) and not just counting from 0-19 inclusive.

Comment: Also covered here: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list

Comment: Thanks, @AChampion for finding a duplicate and posting the docs. Ignore my answer.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks. The 4th block of code in that document does the trick!